# HDDs disconnecting with a loud beep - Faulty motherboard?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, power-supply, sata

I'll make this as short as possible.

**Setup:**

- Mobo:    Gigabyte B550I AORUS PRO AX
- CPU: Ryzen 7 5700x
- GPU: EVGA RTX 3060
- PSU: Corsair SF750 Platinum
- Storage: Crucial MX500 250Gb
- Storage: Samsung 970 PRO 512Gb
- Storage: Toshiba MG08 6TB

**The problems:**

Several, various, but the main one is i bought a new HDD in December of last year that is now not working properly. It's constantly disconnecting with a loud beep, sometimes not even under any load (like when i was installing Windows on an SSD while the HDD wasn't engaged in the process at all).

**Some context:**

Like i said, i bought it in December of last year.

All was working fine at first. At the time i was running a different CPU and mobo. (Ryzen 7 2700x and Asrock Fatal1ty X470 Gaming-ITX/ac). Same PSU, not a singe issue with it whatsoever.

Then in January, i made an upgrade and changed the CPU and mobo to the ones listed above.

It was still working fine at first. Enough that now it's not clear if the upgrade was the immediate cause of the problem. About two weeks after the upgrade it started disconnecting. Sometimes it would hang up the system all together to the point where i couldn't even restart it.

I also have a backup 1 Tb drive. I tried connecting that and it's not working properly either. When connected it's clicking and keeps disconnecting as well. Now it is pretty old, so i can't be 100% sure that's in just the HDD that's at fault.

I have tried running both of these HDDs on a different PC and they seemed to work fine. I tried opening stuff on it, copying huge amounts for large periods of time and it wasn't an issue.
I have also tried swapping the cables, both SATA and power.

Besides this problem the computer works fine-ish. I could game on it for hours with no problems, off of the Toshiba HDD no less and it hadn't disconnected once.I stresstested both the CPU and the GPU several times.I also managed to edit and finish a video project on it. There was an issue where the render would stall half way and both the CPU and the GPU utilization would drop to zero and it would do nothing pretty much, although that could be a Premiere issue.

There's also a slight problem in that i can't use FanControl anymore because it just won't launch, same as Gigabyte's own software for controlling RGB, which isn't a big deal of course, but it just makes me more suspicious that there's something wrong with the board.

CPU can't affect the PC in this sort of way, can it?

**UPDATE:**
I can't believe it, but between the three new things i got in the upgrade, it might have been the case that's the problem all along.
It's an SFF case, DAN A4-H20, which has a PSU cable extension, and i must have been off by one contact or something when putting the cable in, but i pretty much rebuilt it and it's been fine for the past couple days. I'm still wary and on the look out, but it seems to be fine. I also wiped the OS drive clean and installed the stock official build off of Microsoft's site which also fixed a couple issues, like the FanControl not launching. Thanks guys.

**UPDATE 2:**
Issue not fixed, came back after about 3 days. I went for the nuclear-nuclear option and bought a new mobo (same model, new rev). The issue made itself apparent once again as soon as i booted up the PC. With the HDD, mobo and CPU ruled out, the only thing left is the case, or more specifically the extension cable inside it. Been running the PC with the extension bypassed for about a day now and no issues yet. Gonna try and check the cable for any issues and update later.

Comment: From your description my first thought is that the power requirements of your current setup exceed the requirements of the previous one, and your PSU is underpowered.

Comment: The other PC i tested my HDDs on did have a 1000W PSU, so that goes right in line with your suspicion, however back when i ran the 2700x and the x470 mobo i had exactly the same PSU + 1 more SATA drive and it wasn't an issue. Surely a new mobo and CPU can't draw this much more power? And all the wattage calculators suggest i need 395W PSU, so i'm well within that, if they are to be believed.

Comment: It's quite possible. I don't actually know the power requirements of either of these combos, I'm just saying what it sounds like, and your comment with testing on another system supports it. As a best practice, when you offer new info or clarifications as a response to a comment, you should [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1768631/edit) the question and add it directly there. This way everything relevant is easily available without waddling through comment threads. In general, the more details, the better the answer :-)

Comment: @Gorchitsa Your total amount of power may be well withing limits, but it is possible that you are drawing too much on a single power-rail coming from the PSU. Try powering the harddisks from different connectors.

Comment: ... and to add to this, if you test it's again best to respond with an edit "I tested X, result was Y".

Comment: Gotcha, thank you both for responding. Noted. Will try @Tonny suggestion.

Comment: Happy you saved your initial issue, but voting to close. Mainly because the “solution” was to rebuild the system physically and from an OS point of view as well. Which is a “nuclear” option and not really a specific thing done to solve this one issue.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I'm not sure what it means to "close", but yeah, sure. Just to clarify, reinstalling Windows was a separate measure. The HDD stopped disconnecting prior to that. I just did that cause my previous version of Windows was a custom, "lite" one with a bunch of stuff cut, which is why i imagine some software wasn't working properly. I'm 90% sure that the cable reseating is what fixed the main issue.

Comment: “Voting to close…” means a community member (me) is flagging the question to close it. Your “UPDATE” is an answer that you did not post as an answer and the solution might have worked,  but you don’t know what exactly did what to fix it.